# what would be the best way to pose a more general/high level coding question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, architecture

The first part of why I am asking this question is to make sure i post my question in the right place.  My question is going to basically be, "Hey I'm about to make an ASP .net / C# site that does X, at a high level how would you do it?"  Kind of like a brain storm session with people who are, I assume, much more experienced than I.  I am not looking for code or specifics since I know how to Google/code just fine but more like how would you architect everything.  So would I just use regular C#, ASP.net, SQL etc tags?

Also is this an OK question to ask on Stack Overflow?  I don't see many brainstorm-esque questions, mainly just very specific (i.e. "heres my code to do X, why doesnt it work!?" or "can someone give me code to accomplish X") questions.

And lastly I ask because it seems like for some reason when i try to ask a question from a high level I get yelled at in the comments.  All I end up with is people saying "too vague" or asked to "post code."

Any advice?

Comment: stackoverflow is not a place for interesting discussions.  But in your case *maybe* that *programmers.stackexchange.com* could be suitable.

Comment: @TacticalCoder [apparently it didn't work out](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/144762/162) in this case.

Comment: [Real questions have answers.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)

Comment: I think too many people criticize this site for the simplicity of the questions here. It's a great place ask a very simple question and get a fast and simple response. Maybe the answer doesn't make you go "hmm", but it makes you go "oh, why didn't I think of that". For questions that make you go "hmm", check the rest of the internet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This about covers it

> Kind of like a brain storm session with people who are, I assume, much more experienced than I.

You want to start a *discussion* and the FAQ says

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.

so there **is no appropriate way to pose the question on Stack Overflow**.

Comment: what about if i posed the question as, "I am coding my project to do X and i went about it this way which works, but am I going about it the right way or is there a much easier/more efficient way to get the same results (X)."

Comment: @chilleo Check out [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), we are a bit more welcoming on subjective questions, but still a Q&A site and not a discussion forum, we expect questions to be on practical actual problems, similarly to Stack Overflow (thus: no brainstorming / open ended discussions).